# Unable to write using XMLWriter from inside CRM 4.0 plugin execute method

Tags: crm

I am trying to use XMLWriter inside a crm 4.0 plugin. I am using the below code inside Execute Method of the plugin.

```
            XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create("c:\\AccountDetails.xml");

            xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Account Details");
            xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("City", cityName);
            xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
            xmlWriter.Close();
```

But i get the exception "Access To The Path c:\AccountDetails.xml" denied".

Am i missing something? The machine is Windows Server 2003.

Regards,
virmani

Comment: Try adding a subfolder.. The C:\ can be protected because it's your hard drive root.

Comment: It seems like the application you execute does not have the rights to read the xml file. As the path is directly at "C:\", I guess your application needs administrator privileges